# Baby Rudin 9.9 Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The inserted picture shows the statement about linear transformation of a basis. The statement says "Then, every A $\in L(X,Y)$ determines a set of numbers $a_{ij}$ such that $Ax_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij}y_{i}$, $\left(1\leq j\leq n\right)$" Note that $L\left(X,Y\right)$ is the set of all linear transformations of the vector space X into the vector space Y.

From the definition of $A$, $Ax=Y$. However, it is not clear if there exists $A$ such that $Ax_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij}y_{i} , \left(1\leq j\leq n\right)$. Satisfying this equality condition means the following.

$$
Ax_{j}=\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} &...& a_{1n}\\
    ...&...&...&...\\
    a_{m1} &a_{m2} & ...& a_{mn} 
  \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1j}\\
x_{2j}\\
...\\
x_{nj}
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}a_{11}x_{1j}+...+a_{1n}x_{nj}\\
a_{21}x_{1j}+...+a_{2n}x_{nj}\\
a_{m1}x_{1j}+...+a_{mn}x_{nj}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij}y_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij}\begin{pmatrix}y_{1i}\\
y_{2i}\\
...\\
y_{mi}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1j}y_{11}+...+a_{mj}y_{1m}\\
a_{1j}y_{21}+...+a_{mj}y_{2m}\\
...\\
a_{1j}y_{m1}+...+a_{mj}y_{mm}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}x_{1j}+...+a_{1n}x_{nj}\\
a_{21}x_{1j}+...+a_{2n}x_{nj}\\
...\\
a_{m1}x_{1j}+...+a_{mn}x_{nj}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1j}y_{11}+...+a_{mj}y_{1m}\\
a_{1j}y_{21}+...+a_{mj}y_{2m}\\
...\\
a_{1j}y_{m1}+...+a_{mj}y_{mm}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
should hold. However, this is not very clear for me.

"Picture":
[image: Rudin p210]

Comment: If I understand correctly, your question is about the existence of a linear map such that $Ax_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij}y_{i} , \left(1\leq j\leq n\right)$, given $a_{ij}$? Can you prove that $A(\sum^n_{j=1} \beta_j x_j) = \sum^m_{i=1}  \sum^n_{j=1} a_{ij} \beta_j y_i$ is a (unique) linear map that satisfies this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that symbol $A$ in the equation $Ax_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij}y_{i}$ is not for a matrix. Here $A$ is just a linear transformation. Generally letter $T$ is used for linear transformation.

What author actually trying to say here is, for every $T\in L(X,Y)$, there corresponds an $m \times n$ matrix $A$,(author uses $[A]$ for this) and entries $a_{ij}$ of $A$ are given by $Tx_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij}y_{i}$.

This correspondence is actually a bijection between $L(X,Y)$ and $\mathbb{F}^{m\times n}$.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be overcomplicating it. You don't need to write each $x_j$ as $\begin{pmatrix}x_{1j}\\...\\x_{nj}\end{pmatrix}$. Instead, what Rudin probably means is
\begin{equation*}
x_j=\begin{pmatrix}0_1\\...\\1_j\\...\\0_n\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
where every coordinate is $0$ except for the $j$th coordinate which is $1$. I have used subindices to indicate which coordinate the values belong to. Similarly,
\begin{equation*}
y_i=\begin{pmatrix}0_1\\...\\1_i\\...\\0_m\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

This way, verifying the equality is pretty straightforward.
The computation is what you've already done, except that you change the basis, that is,
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_{11} & ... & a_{1n}\newline
  ... & ... & ...\newline
  a_{m1} & ... & a_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0_1 \newline
... \newline
1_j \newline
... \newline
0_n \newline
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \sum_{i=1}^m a_{i1}y_i\newline ...\newline \sum_{i=1}^m a_{in}y_i \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{1i}(x_j)_i \newline ...\newline \sum_{i=1}^n a_{mi}(x_j)_i \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$
=\begin{pmatrix} a_{1j}\cdot 1 \newline ...\newline a_{mj}\cdot 1\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} a_{1j}\newline 0 \newline ...\end{pmatrix} + ... + \begin{pmatrix} ...\newline 0 \newline a_{mj}\end{pmatrix}
=\sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij}y_i
$$

Comment: Thanks! Do you know in which page he introduces the definition of $x_{j}$?

Comment: I haven't actually read the book, "define" probably isn't the best word. What I mean is that's likely the convention he's using in this section. What he claims only makes sense if each column corresponds to an element of $X$. Normally, how I think of the notation $v=\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\...\\v_n\end{pmatrix}$ is that it represents a linear function from $v$ to $X$, which so happens to be the coordinates of $v$ when $v=v_1x_1+...+v_nx_n$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you possibly calculate this question since I cannot reach to the conclusion. Also, what does he want to say here in page 210?

Comment: I just edited my answer to add the computations. Also, I just realised that I made amistake in my answer, and have corrected that as well. It should be clearer now. Could you attach a photo of the page 210 you are referring to?